# SELECT Mysql - Replacing value in one column based on another column

Tags: mysql, select

Here is my table:

```
ID     |     MainLink
----------------------
1      |     1111
2      |     1111
3      |     2222
4      |     3333
5      |     2222
6      |     4444
```

I need to be able to select and replace the ID value based on a distinct value from the MainLink Column. The new value for the ID Column will have to be the first ID value found.
This is what I would like:

```
ID     |     MainLink
----------------------
1      |     1111
1      |     1111
3      |     2222
4      |     3333
3      |     2222
6      |     4444
```

Hope this is clear. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Is `ID` a primary key?

Comment: Yes, ID is a primary key.

Comment: Would a distinct result set with an occurrence count suffice instead? As that could be done with a simple `GROUP BY` on `MainLink`, a `MIN(ID)` and a `COUNT(*)`. Duplicate rows seem like a waste.

Comment: As you said `Yes, ID is a primary key.` you can't replace it.You can't have same value twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return all `MainLinks` and the lowest value of `ID` available:

```
SELECT tmp.ID, t.MainLink
  FROM Table1 t
  JOIN ( SELECT MainLink, MIN(ID) AS ID
           FROM Table1
          GROUP BY MainLink
       ) AS tmp ON ( tmp.MainLink = t.MainLink );
```

Result (see [example on SQLFiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af0fe/4):

```
ID  MainLinke
1   1111
1   1111
3   2222
4   3333
3   2222
6   4444
```

Comment: What is the "t" for before MainLink and after Table1?

Comment: Following Peter's answer, I tried to select 2 tables in the same query. This is what I came up with:  
  
SELECT tmp.ID, t.MainLink, a.ID_Product, a.Name, a.Returned, t.LAXS  
 FROM Stock_Items a,StockAccount t  
 JOIN ( SELECT MainLink, MIN(ID) AS ID  
 FROM StockAccount  
 GROUP BY MainLink  
 ) AS tmp ON ( tmp.MainLink = t.MainLink );  
 WHERE  
 t.ID=a.ID_Product AND  
 a.Name='' AND  
 a.Returned='' AND  
 t.LAXS='Yes'    

I get "#2008 - MySQL client ran out of memory".  Not sure why since the output should not be that big.  Any idea?

Comment: `t` is a table alias, it allows me to refer to `Table1` as `t`. I'm afraid I cannot help you with your memory problem, try searching online and ask another question (maybe better at http://dba.stackexchange.com/) if you cannot solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `update` and `join`.  The key is to calculate the minimum `id` for each `MainLink` in a subquery:

```
update table t join
       (select MainLink, min(id) as minid
        from table t
        group by MainLink
       ) ml
       on t.MainLink = ml.MainLink and t.id > ml.minid
   set t.id = ml.minid;
```

I do find it strange that you actually want to create duplicates in your table.